# What is JAXB and why would I use it?

Tags: java, jaxb

There is guy here swearing that JAXB is the greatest thing since sliced bread.  I am curious to see what Stack Overflow users think the use case is for JAXB and what makes it a good or a bad solution for that case.

Comment: Read this Article(Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)) this is best one. URL : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html#unmars

Comment: Message from 2020: "Stay the hell away from Jaxb and xml altogether!"

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I'm a big fan of JAXB for manipulating XML. Basically, it provides a solution to this problem (I'm assuming familiarity with XML, Java data structures, and XML Schemas):

Working with XML is difficult. One needs a way to take an XML file - which is basically a text file - and convert it into some sort of data structure, which your program can then manipulate.

JAXB will take an XML Schema that you write and create a set of classes that correspond to that schema. The JAXB utilities will create the hierarchy of data structures for manipulating that XML.

JAXB can then be used to read an XML file, and then create instances of the generated classes - laden with the data from your XML. JAXB also does the reverse: takes java classes, and generates the corresponding XML.

I like JAXB because it is easy to use, and comes with Java 1.6 (if you are using 1.5, you can download the JAXB .jars.) The way it creates the class hierarchy is intuitive, and in my experience, does a decent job abstracting away the "XML" so that I can focus on "data".

So to answer your question: I would expect that, for small XML files, JAXB might be overkill. It requires you to create and maintain an XML schema, and to use "standard textbook methods" of utilizing Java classes for data structures. (Main classes, small inner-classes to represent "nodes", and a huge hierarchy of them.) So, JAXB is probably not that great for a simple linear list of "preferences" for an application.

But if you have a rather complex XML schema, and lots of data contained within it, then JAXB is fantastic. In my project, I was converting large amounts of data between binary (which was consumed by a C program) and XML (so that humans could consume and modify that data). The resulting XML Schema was nontrivial (many levels of hierarchy, some fields could be repeated, others could not) so JAXB was helpful in being able to manipulate that.

Comment: JAXB can be done without XSD.  You can use annotations: https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Mapping_your_favorite_class.html

Comment: JAXB is a spec (like JPA or JAXP), meaning that there are multiple implementations (Metro, EclipseLink, etc).  If you have a problem with one you can switch to another implementation.  You can also take advantage of extensions offered by different vendors.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, Metro is a JAXB implementation ?! Isn't Metro a WSIT implementation ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana - I guess I should of referred to it as Project JAXB (https://jaxb.java.net/) which is part of Metro the JAX-WS implementation (https://metro.java.net/).

Comment: FYI, JAXB is being removed from Java SE 11. See [*JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320). This action is being taken as part of the [Modularization of Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), and the handover of [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) technologies to the [*Jakarta EE*](https://jakarta.ee) project. You will have to add the JAXB API & an implementation to your project.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a reason not to use it:  performance suffers.  There is a good deal of overhead when marshaling and unmarshaling.  You might also want to consider another API for XML-Object binding -- such as JiBX:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Also consider using the tool XSD2Jibx if you're having trouble with bindings - it's in "alpha" status, but it's really helpful illustrating the classes and bindings it likes with XSD schemas...now, if only it stopped using SQL date by default, and used Java util Date instead...

Comment: Bullshit. JAXB is pretty fast, as long as you use fast parser (like Woodstox), overhead of maybe 30-40% compared to manual binding. JiBX is fine, no problem with it, but performance difference is not huge.

Comment: I have used JAXB on several projects, and continue to use it.  But its important to understand how it compares to other frameworks.  If you are marshaling/unmarshaling documents that are hundreds of megabytes, and time is important - JiBX is a good alternative.  JAXB == reflection, JiBX == byte code instrumentation.

Answer (score 21):

I use JAXB at work all the time and I really love it. It's perfect for complex XML schemas that are always changing and especially good for random access of tags in an XML file.

I hate to pimp but I just started a blog and this is literally the first thing I posted about!

Check it out here:

http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2010/04/21/getting-started-with-jaxb/

Comment: Clear example on your blog.  Upvoted for that.  :-)

Answer (score 20):

It's an "ORM for XML". Most often used alongside JAX-WS (and indeed the Sun implementations are developed together) for WS Death Star systems.

Answer (score 9):

With JAXB you can automatically create XML representations of your objects (marshalling) and object representations of the XML (unmarshalling).

As far as the XML Schema is concerned, you have two choices:

- Generate Java classes from an XSD
- Generate an XSD from your Java classes

There are also some simpler XML serialization libraries like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) or [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) that might be alternatives.

Comment: These aren't binding frameworks, they are serialization libraries. A good binding framework can map any XML to an isomorphic object graph or back again. These simple serialization mechanisms produce and consume a fixed, non-standard XML schema.

Comment: Thanks erickson, I've only worked with JAXB and wanted to make sure I mention alternatives. I'll edit my answer based on your input.

Comment: Actually, while XStream is ok, it's not really simpler, since both are very simple. And Digester is NOT simple, just simplistic.

Comment: Someone please mention JAXB-2.0 using Annotations. Between that an a few XmlAdapter classes, I can map any schema to any existing Java structure.

Answer (score 8):

JAXB is great if you have to code to some external XML spec defined as an XML schema (`xsd`).

For example, you have a trading application and you must report the trades to the *Uber Lame Trade Reporting App* and they've given you `ultra.xsd` to be getting on with. Use the `$JAVA_HOME/bin/xjc` compiler to turn the XML into a bunch of Java classes (e.g. `UltraTrade`).

Then you can just write a simple *adapter* layer to convert your trade objects to `UltraTrades` and use the `JAXB` to marshal the data across to Ultra-Corp. **Much** easier than messing about converting your trades into their XML format.

Where it all breaks down is when Ultra-Corp haven't actually obeyed their own spec, and the trade `price` which they have down as a `xsd:float` should actually be expressed as a `double`!

Comment: Also note that you CAN do code-first: start with beans, generate schema iff you need it.

Answer (score 7):

**Why we need JAXB?**
The remote components (written in Java) of web services uses XML as a mean to exchange messages between each other. **Why XML?** Because XML is considered light weight option to exchange message on Networks with limited resources.
So often we need to convert these XML documents into objects and vice versa. E.g: Simple Java POJO Employee can be used to send Employee data to remote component( also a Java programme).

```
class Employee{
 String name;
 String dept;
 ....
}
```

This Pojo should be converted (Marshall) in to XML document as follow:

```
<Employee>
  <Name>...</Name>
  <Department>...</Department>
</Employee>
```

And at the remote component, back to Java object from XML document (Un-Marshall).

**What is JAXB?**

JAXB is a library or a tool to perform this operation of Marshalling and UnMarshalling. It spares you from this headache, as simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

You can also check out JIBX too. It is also a very good xml data binder, which is also specialized in OTA (Open Travel Alliance) and is supported by AXIS2 servers. If you're looking for performance and compatibility, you can check it out :

http://jibx.sourceforge.net/index.html

Answer (score 0):

JAXB provides improved performance via default marshalling optimizations.
JAXB defines a programmer API for reading and writing Java objects to and from XML documents, thus simplifying the reading and writing of XML via Java.